# warning in MSSQL 2008 and PHP5 connectivity

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to write a program in PHP to connect to MSSQL...

I am using PHP5.4.24, MSSQL server 2008 express edition, Apache HTTP 2.2...

I put `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts` and `php_sqlsrv_54_ts` file in PHP/ext folder and mentioned the extensions in `php.ini` file but while starting the apache is getting the below eeror:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
>
> [Wed Mar 05 10:48:24 2014] [notice] Child 14728: Child process is running

I tried with both ts and nts dll files but it did not work... Please tell me if above softwares are compatible or any other dll is needed..

I tried different solutions available on stackoverflow but it did not worked..